# SQL Result set to XML (with attribute in parent tags)

Tags: sql, xml, attributes, resultset

```
Table Structure

ID    Name    Dept    Salary
1     John    IT      1000
2     Jamie   HR      2000
3     Ron     FN      3000

XML needed as follows

<Data>
    <EMP Id=1>
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Dept>IT</Dept>
        <Salary>1000</Salary>
    </Emp>
    <EMP Id=2>
        <Name>Jamie</Name>
        <Dept>HR</Dept>
        <Salary>2000</Salary>
    </Emp>
    <EMP Id=3>
        <Name>Ron</Name>
        <Dept>FN</Dept>
        <Salary>3000</Salary>
    </Emp>
</Data>
```

I am using following DB query to construct XML from the resultset -

```
SELECT *   FROM <DBName>  FOR XML PATH('EMP'), ROOT ('DATA')
```

Not sure how to get the above desired XML i.e with attribute "id" as mentioned above

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: If this question is solved, it would be very kind of you, to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
SELECT ID AS [@Id]
      ,Name
      ,Dept
      ,Salary 
FROM YourTable
FOR XML PATH('EMP'), ROOT ('Data')
```

And be carefull with case sensitivity. In XML `DATA` is **not equal** to `Data`

Comment: I do not want to hardcode the tag names. it should come dynamic. Thus, I am facing issue.

Comment: 1) You should have mentioned this 2) There is **no chance** to name the aliases dynamically, although you might trick around with dynamically created statements using `EXEC`. 3) How should the statement know, which columns should be attributes and which should not?

Comment: Got is, now it is working.. SELECT ID AS [@ID],*
FROM <name>
FOR XML PATH('EMP'), ROOT ('DATA')

Comment: @ankurtaunk In general: You should -  in most cases - avoid using the `*` sign to cover *all columns*. Sure, there are good places to use this, but you must **know for sure** the count, type and order of your columns. Now and in all future. Working code might break if you change a table's structure due to `*`... Coding means typing :-)

Comment: @ankurtaunk, Your solution will bring you the ID twice... Once as attribute and again as element... Don't know if you want this...

Comment: I agree, I will get the ID twice. Ummm, let me see how I can tweak my  design. But, thanks buddy for this real quick help

Comment: @ankurtaunk There's no tweaking, just typing :-) You might create the column list out of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS, but this is even more typing... And you would need some extra effort to recognize the columns you do not want as elements...